# Prevent IFS to stop on new lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ifs

I have a multiline string which I want to transform into an array by using a single delimiter `|`. However, when setting `IFS=|` it will stop right before a new line appears:

```
IFS='|' read -a VARS <<< "var1|var2|var3
                          var4|var5|var6
                          var7|var8|var9"

echo ${VARS[@]}
#output => var1 var2 var3
```

I am wondering why the remaining lines won’t be evaluated and how to prevent that of happening, being able to assign every variable regardless the presence of a new line?

Comment: `IFS` is only used for splitting fields in a single string. `read` will read only one line at a time. Your here string consists of *three* lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your `IFS` to `|` and `\n` and use `-d` to use another delimiter besides newline. You also need to keep your values intact. Spaces also get to be included.

```
IFS=$'|\n' read -d '' -a VARS <<< "var1|var2|var3
var4|var5|var6
var7|var8|var9"
```

`read` by default only reads up to the first newline character unless changed by `-d`. `''` is also synonymous to `$'\0'` as an argument to it.

#### Another point

Spaces (including newlines) inside double-quotes are not silently ignored. They are also included literally as a value.

So perhaps what you really should have done is:

```
IFS='|' read -a VARS <<< "var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|var6|var7|var8|var9"
```

Comment: that is great konsolebox. Thanks for this. Any ideas why `IFS='|' read -a VARS <<< \`echo var1|var2|var3\`` won’t have the same effect (since it is the output of a command?

Comment: @zanona If you're not quoting `echo var1|var2|var3`, `|` would be interpreted as a pipe on a simple command.

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox, just figure out when it is a command output I should use `< <(command)` instead `<<<\`command\`` that works now

Answer (score 3):

In bash, the proper syntax to write multiline strings is the following :

```
IFS='|' read -a VARS <<< "var1|var2|var3 \
                          var4|var5|var6 \
                          var7|var8|var9"
echo ${VARS[@]}
#>var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9

#However, you will have
echo "${VARS[@]}"
#>var1 var2 var3                           var4 var5 var6                           var7 var8 var9
```

If you want to write your string as a multiline one and remove completely spaces, you could  add `|` to your existing `$IFS` instead of erasing it

```
IFS=$IFS'|' read -a VARS <<< "var1|var2|var3 \
                              var4|var5|var6 \
                              var7|var8|var9"
echo "${VARS[@]}"
#>var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9
```

Comment: I really didn’t know about breaking lines with `\` thank you very much for the tip Plotoux